# Элемент flexbox контейнера не держит свою длину

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Проблема заключается в том что первый элемент, которому я хочу задать его базовую длину (которая условно должна быть 100px) - почему-то уменьшается.

```css
.main{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
  width:500px;
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
}
.item1{
  flex:1 1 100px;
  background:#979797;
}
.item2{
  flex:1 1 auto;
  background:#373737;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="item1">1</div>
 <div class="item2">Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности требуют определения и уточнения систем массового участия.</div>
<div>
```

Как я выяснил виной всему свойство flex-shrink, если заменить с 1 на 0 (у item1) то первый элемент не будет участвовать в сжатии и он сохранит свою длину, которая была написана ему изначально. Вопрос в том почему flex-shrink влияет на первый элемент если второму написано значение auto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в том что второй блок уходит за рамки flex контейнера. И как я говорил ранее всему виной свойство `flex-shrink`. Если мы обнулим у обоих контейнеров это свойство это будет значить, что сжатие к ним не применяется. А теперь давайте глянем сколько же суммарно по ширине будут показывать эти два контейнера. У меня первый контейнер 100px как мне нужно и второй 1180px. Почему 1180px потому что текст в строчку потребляет столько места (четкого ограничения по ширине нет, а стоит значение во `flex-basis:auto;`). Вот отсюда и идут все эти числа. Но я спрашивал почему второй контейнер забирает слишком много пространства и даже съедает кусок от первого. Все дело в том что у обоих включен `flex-shrink`. Они оба будут под воздействием сжатия независимо от начальных ширин. Ну а как же узнать конкретно как все это должно сжиматься?

Есть такая формула:

```
ширинаНужногоКонтейнера*коэфициентСжатияНужногоКонтейнера/(ширинаN1Контейнера*коэфициентСжатияN1Контейнера+...+ширинаN+XКонтейнера*коэфициентСжатияN+XКонтейнера)*(ШиринаДоступногоПространства-(СуммаШиринВсехКонтейнеровБезКоэфициентовСжатия))+ширинаНужногоКонтейнера
```

Если эту формулу перевести на мой пример она будет выглядеть так:

```js
console.log(100*1/(100*1+1180*1)*(500-(100+1180))+100)
```

Тут я получаю ширину первого контейнера, остальные ширины можно получить не затрудняясь.

Собственно вот и ответ на вопрос, который я хотел получить.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Все у вас работает, измените первому блоку `flex: 1 0 100px` и он не будет уменьшатся, а лучше `flex: 0 0 100px` чтобы еще и не рос. Возможно у Вас с браузером конфликт, я бы посоветовал отдельно использовать каждое свойство.

```css
.main{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
}
.item1{
  flex:0 0 100px;
  background:#979797;
}
.item2{
  flex:1 1 auto;
  background:#373737;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="item1">Заголовок</div>
 <div class="item2">Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности требуют определения и уточнения систем массового участия. Повседневная практика показывает, что новая модель организационной деятельности в значительной степени обуславливает создание форм развития. Таким образом сложившаяся структура организации обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании новых предложений.</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Зачем вы пишите то что я описал после примера? Вы вопрос внимательно читали?

Comment: Потому как все работает. Я повторил ваши слова и добавил еще 0 на рост.

Comment: Еще раз повторяю вопрос вы внимательно читали? Меня интересует не рабочий вариант, а причина по которой первый контейнер имеет длину меньше установленной.

Comment: Поверьте, читать я умею. Еще раз говорю, "Ваш код рабочий!" Если добавить написать первому элементу `flex: 0 0 100px` Первый элемент у вас 100px. В чем вопрос? Во втором делайте что хотите. Скрин приложу выше.

Comment: А я не говорю что мой код не рабочий. Вы читать не умеете или вопрос не понимаете? Еще раз: `причина по которой первый контейнер имеет длину меньше установленной`.

Comment: Напишу, последний раз, Нет, удалю ответ да и только, в приложенном скрине первый блок 100px он не  `имеет длину меньше установленной`

Comment: Я кстати уже разобрался в чем дело. А минусы ставить это низко. Неужто я задел ваше самолюбие? Ответ я опубликую чуть позже если заинтересованы в нем.